# SQA Testing: async callback javascript test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, selenium-webdriver

I am newbie to test automation. I came cross this question a couple of times in a different flavor.

**First one**: A method returns the values in random order to a list. Now I have to write a test to assert values in the list are correct.

**Second one**: There is javascript async call back method that returns chunks of data. How do I test completeness of this data is correct?

I may need to write a test script to test this one.  I am not sure if these both questions are similar in nature, but I would like to know the answers or guidance to refer to. Appreciate help.

Comment: Can you show us what you've written so far so we can try and improve on it? Where are these values you need to check coming from? Are they being displayed on a screen? What is the Selenium relevance? You need to help yourself first before we can help you! The more information you give us the better we can help ...

Comment: My answer to those questions are: First question is related to Junit. I create a Hashmap with all expected values as keys. As I receive random values from function, I increment the value from 0 to 1. After method completed then I check the map for all 1 s. Second question is related to a map Ui something like google maps. As a map gets populated with a set of data it happens by loading chunks of Ui pieces.  I don't know answer for it.   I am also looking for a better responses to what I mentioned for first.